# I have a resources (JSON file) which consists of all my required data from the database fetching data to add dropdown

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-spinner

- my Json Response for country :

  `{"searchvalues":[{"id":"1","name":"india"},{"id":"2","name":"srilanka"}],"success":1}`
- country name add to spinner by using : `"countryadapter.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));"`
- Drop down working fine, when i"m select "coutry".example i"m selecting "india" i want "id" from `({"id":"1","name":"India"}).`
- My requirement only get selected item id from `({"id":"1","name":"India"})`.

  ```
  country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
              View view, int position, long id) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      String  countryname = country.getSelectedItem().toString();
          StringRequest state=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, D_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

              @Override
              public void onResponse(String response) {

                  try {
                      JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(response);
      JSONArray  jsonArray =jsnobject.getJSONArray("searchvalues");

                  distadapter.clear();
                   for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                       JSONObject obj= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                   }

                  } catch (JSONException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }

              }
          }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

              @Override
              public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              }
          });
  ```

Comment: you want only country name in your spinner??

Comment: Your last bullet point isn't clear. I'm not sure what you are actually saying. Please elaborate.

Comment: First your Json is invalid. It should be like this
{"countrys":[{"id":"1","name":"India"},{"id":"2","name":"srilanka"}]}

Comment: You can do it in different ways 1)Simple way: If the position no + 1 in your array passed to spinner matches with id then on item selected you can go with position no + 1 2) Maintain a ArrayList<Country> countries; with Country have id and name attributes

Comment: tq for replay @Amarbir Singh, i want country name to drop down working fine, when im select india that moment i want country id from my responce({"id":"1","name":"India"})..guide me

Comment: Exactly ,your json file is invalid get it validated from http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @naveenreddy First correct your Json. When Json seems valid then just get the object from country array. It will give you id.

Comment: if your id is starting from 1 then do this---> 

                spinner = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                int count = position; //this would give you the id of the selected item

Comment: Creative Android @ my json responce is :{"countrys":[{"id":"1","name":"india"},{"id":"2","name":"srilanka"}],"success":1}

Answer (score 0):

When you get position selected from click of item spinner.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject("Your Response");
JSONArray countries = object.getJSONArray("searchvalues");

String id = countries.getJSONObject(position).getString("id");
```

From this way you can get ID

Comment: tq @but its not working for me..my json changed like this : {"searchvalues":[{"id":"1","name":"india"},{"id":"2","name":"srilanka"}],"success":1} , exaat my reuirement is : when im select country then get id send to server, then im get state list ..

Answer (score -1):

Try this once you validate your JSON,

```
class Country
{
    int id;
    String name;
}

List<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();


country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String  countryname = country.getSelectedItem().toString();
            StringRequest state=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, D_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray  jsonArray =jsnobject.getJSONArray("searchvalues");

                    distadapter.clear();
                     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                         JSONObject obj= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                         Country tempCountry;
                         int id = obj.getInt("id");
                         String name = obj.getString("name");  
                         tempCountry.id =id;
                         tempCountry.name = name;
                         countryList.add(tempCountry);

                     }
               for(Country temp: countryList)
                {
                   if(countryName.equals(temp.name))
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"id : "+temp.id,Toast.LONG).show();
                }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```